# Using Axios with isLoaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Goal:
Use axios instead of fetch in order to display the data in the table

Problem:
Somehow it doesn't work when I use axios in relation to 'isLoaded'
What part of the code am I missing?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cntoqk?

Info:
Newbie in Reactjs

---

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      listData: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    /** 
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1')
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          listData: data
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    */

    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1')
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          listData: data
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.listData &&
                this.state.listData.map(item => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={item.id.toString()}>
                      <td>{item.id}</td>
                      <td>{item.name}</td>
                      <td>{item.email}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in line 34, it must be `response.data` ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Floyd already pointed out, your code should look like this

```
 axios
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1')
  .then(response =>
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
      listData:  response.data
    })
  );
```